# Why was silage only invented in the 19th century?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, agriculture, inventions

For thousands of years in the Northern climates mankind had to slaughter a large proportion of their livestock due to a shortage of winter fodder.

What prevented mankind from using silage/haylage until the 19th Century?

Was it just that no-one had the idea until the 19th Century?

Comment: A guess is that there just wasn't that much surplus of food, space and labour to actually store it. Don't forget that slaughtered livestock became food.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: This is a good question. +1 Has enough quality to be in History SE.(Even though the OP might be wrong.)

Comment: I think that perhaps you have a misconception here.  It was not so much that pre-mechanization farmers couldn't store feed for their animals, as it was that the storage was labor intensive.  In the other seasons, livestock basically feeds itself.  To feed livestock through the winter, humans have to do much of the work of cutting, transporting, and storing food for it.  So you'd only store food for draft animals & breeding stock.

Comment: The livestock wasn't killed in winter because of the lack of crops to feed them. The livestock was killed in winter to feed the people, who had little else to eat. Also, meat can much easier be preserved in cold weather, therefore butchering large animals (without having half of it spoiled) was much easier at home.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Judging by [History of Silage](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292876056_History_of_Silage) by Wilkinson et al (2003), the premise behind the question is somewhat inaccurate.

> Silage making is probably more than 3000 yr old. The ancient Egyptians and Greeks stored grain and whole forage crops in silos. Reviews of the history of silage refer to the mural in the Naples Museum, which shows whole-crop cereals being harvested and loaded into a small stone-built silo (Shukking, 1976; Woolford, 1984). Kirstein (1963) mentioned that silos were found in the ruins of Carthage, indicating that forage was ensiled there at around 1200 Be. Cato (cited by Shukking, 1976) noted that the Teutons in the first century stored green fodder in pits in the ground and then covered the pits with dung.
>
> Little is known about silage making between about AD 100 and the eighteenth century, although it is likely that ensiling of forage crops continued to be practiced on a small scale throughout this period. According to Shukking (1976), grass was ensiled in Italy in the thirteenth century, and ensiling was practiced in the northern Alps, Sweden, and the Baltic region early in the eighteenth century. By the middle of the nineteenth century, interest in the ensiling of grass, sugarbeet tops (Beta vul- garis L.), and other crops had spread beyond the Baltic and Germany to most other European countries.

There's a small caveat here, which is that the authors of the article seem to file just about anything that's in a silo as silage. By contrast, I'm assuming you're meaning the sauerkraut version of hay that is used to feed livestock when they can't graze outdoors.

I've only skimmed the couple of pages that followed, but if I'm not mistaking this captures why it caught the interest of late 19th century farmers:

> The initial enthusiasm for silage in the UK was reflected in the encouragement for the adoption of the technology from government, agricultural societies, and leading landowners, who recognized that the main advantage of silage was that it was less susceptible to total failure than either hay or root crops.

Put another way, before that they'd simply use plain hay, with all of its associated problems -- of which there are, apparently, many. (I'm no specialist by any stretch, so I'll direct you to the paper for the details.)

The paper doesn't say why it only spread like wildfire almost overnight in the late 19th (which it basically did) or why it did only then. One might speculate that hitherto benefits of a procedure known in the Baltic and Germany spread slowly in that area until, suddenly, the railroad came along and then it spread it far and wide. But that's just speculation.

Comment: Jeez, before I finished writing a Qcomment… It started to go like this: "I know what livestock is, but call me the dumbest possible SE user: what is silage? Does it have 'advantages/benefits*? If yes, which are these, when was that system introduced…" / Ie: please expand…

Comment: @LangLangC: Silage is like sauerkraut, for but hay. It's used as animal feed during winters.

Comment: I wrote "call me", not "treat me like that in comments"… ;) If you answer before a Q is refined, the refinement needs to be in the A? (Flag once read as obsolete…)

Comment: @LangLangC: does the edit address your question?

Comment: Not really. Despite me knowing about it: The Q as written leaves open to me what the problem really is, how it is framed in Western agriculture, what the dev was what was before … (You have a wide open space to cover… and ample opportunity…)

Comment: @LangLangC: True, though to my credit OP's question in that lens sounds like the kind of topic that could easily turn into a Master's dissertation. :D The article I linked to seems fairly good, btw. It's available on everyone's favorite scientific website if you're curious to read about the details.

Comment: The paper [Silage in Britain, I880-I990:](https://www.bahs.org.uk/AGHR/ARTICLES/44n1a5.pdf) also discusses the timescale of developments on the continent, both in the South of Europe (Italy) in the medieval period and the later adoption in the northern parts.

Comment: I'm not an expert either, but my grandfather raised cattle (and kept a few horses), and had a barn full of hay for the winter. So whatever the "problems" with using hay are, they weren't bad enough to impair its use for this purpose into the modern era. He also raised soybeans, but didn't have a silo himself. I'm guessing it was sold as it was harvested.

Comment: @T.E.D.: To me the real wtf in this question was that there's a thing that might be best described as pickled hay for the sake of keeping the stuff fresh over the winter. :D I had *no* idea, in spite of having been surrounded by cows in my childhood. And that might speak mountains about how little we or people back then paid attention to what feed cattle was eating day in day out.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - Honestly, I probably wouldn't have remembered the hay bales, except they were so much freaking fun to play with as a kid. Tried playing in the soybean hopper too, but got yelled at for that one. (Think "country ball pit")

Comment: @T.E.D. I'd say hay is actually easier to make & store than silage, unless you're having a very wet summer. With silage, you really have to get the storage bit right or it goes off badly, and you need a silo. Silage, being compacted and heavy, is also more difficult to 'serve' (trust me, I know from years of personal experience) but is more nutritious (and smells nice!). I don't think silage is worth the effort for small farmers, but for medium to large dairy (especially) farmers it's almost a 'must'.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy [This link](https://forages.oregonstate.edu/nfgc/eo/onlineforagecurriculum/instructormaterials/availabletopics/mechanicalharvest/silage) is useful and pretty much tallies with my personal experience. One thing it doesn't seem to mention is that making small quantities of silage is tricky, and there would be a fairly high percentage of loss. As farms grew in size, silage became more viable. Hay is not actually difficult to make and store. You just need to make sure it is really dried in the field (and kept dry in storage), and have cats handy to deal with rats.

Comment: @LangLangC haha you ignorant. Me neither (even in my language). I understand now it's one kind of fermented hay, made by silo, part of it being made from corn, but technically I don't get it perfectly. lol.

Comment: @LarsBosteen That link is quite useful, but also one-sided. Silage has advantages for *large farms*, as the producer profits, so do the animals suffer and quality degrades. It is an expensive and risky process that leads to fodder previously not eaten by livestock & largely unsuitable for horses or cattle. Except for those parameters measured in industry: yep, bulk, ie protein goes up, fat & milk increases. Animal health goes down as does taste. Do you remember the large hordes of beet & maize eating buffalos? Silo and silage seem to be confused here? Hay has few, even if significant problems.

Comment: @LangLangC I'm not sure where you're getting your info from, and I'm certainly prepared to accept that large industrial farms may well be using silage in cattle's diet in ways which are not good for them, but  I've never heard of silage being harmful as part of a mixed diet (with barley and hay, for example), unless the silage is damaged or has been contaminated in some way. However, it is less suitable for beef cattle.

Comment: @LarsBosteen The 'mixed diet' is key. *Optimally prepared* silage *in very small amounts* can be added, to positive effect (more nutrients). And optimally means mainly grass/hay anyway, *no soy*… Wild or close to nature living beasts do not eat exclusively grass, but also 'meat' (worms, insects etc). If the proportion of silage exceeds a quite low threshold the advantages silage has are increasingly exclusively for owners and sellers, but no longer for animals or buyers (price is mixed, taste is taste (corn-finished beef=disgusting), health unidirectional down in both cases, eg PUFAprofile)

Comment: @LarsBosteen - I don't remember cats in the hay barn. To hear Grandpa Bus tell it, he had rattlesnakes for that purpose.

Comment: @T.E.D.: in less wild areas, like Europe, we make do with cats. ;-D

Comment: I have a memory about a swedish 30s film there the main character jokes about newcomers who wants to conserve hay....   The current type of dragon eggs is depending on a air tight cover ie an plastic cocong, with that the process is automatic (but  be sure that the amount of earth in the grass on the inside is low.)

Answer (score 1):

TL,DR: Maybe proper ensilaging is only feasible with some degree of mechanisation

Ensilaging crops (whole crop silage is actually pretty common as fodder) or grass is somewhat involved: You need to chop the plant matter down to a few cm, spread in layers < 30 cm and the press is to avoid air pockets. Air pockets mean mold. During the actual ensilaging (the fermentation), a lot of excess water with a high acid content is set free and needs to be kept somehwere. When the silage is fed, there's a certain minimum amount per day - i think the silo face (the sruface you feed from) should advance a meter per day at least because air will enter the silage stack, again leading to mold. In modern aplications the silo is usually covered by a foil, but that is not strictly neccessary (no foil means the top layer spoils).

A silo can be as simple as a blacktop area, more typically it's blacktop with sturdy concrete walls (with some protection) an three sides and a drainage system. However the structure has to handle the weight of the silage and the vehicles, as well as the agressive leachate - I've once met the operator of a biogas plant, his silo was in a limestone area and he had to ecavate the ground 2 o 3 m deep and haul in granite to ensure a lasting foundation (*maybe* the structural engineer and geotechnician where too cautios).

The point of the matter is that ensilaging has an economy of scale aspect and also requires some mechanization. I don't know for sure, but I would suspect that some form of harvester is required to do the chopping. The first harvester was invented in the 1830ties, with large comine havesters becoming common in the late 19th century.